# iOS Restore Purchases in TestFlight

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, applet, testflight

I have a mobile app, which for `iOS` I am testing with TestFlight.

After I make a successful "Non-Renewing Subscription" purchase, I would expect to see the purchase history when I call `Restore Purchases`. When I make a purchase through the TestFlight app, I do not see any historic purchases.

**Question**

Is this normal behaviour because this is a test environment, and the purchases don't really exist? Or, should I expect to see the historic purchases?

If one cannot see the historic purchases, how do you test `Restore Purchases`?

**Code:**

```
  this.iap.restorePurchases().then((purchases: any[]) => {
      // purchases are empty
  });
```

The get Products does return the products successfully.

```
  this.iap.getProducts(this.PRODUCT_IDS).then((products: any[]) => {
     ...
  });
```

ps. When I run this same code in `Android` `restorePurchases` does return the historic purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to table 1-2 and the accompanying text in the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2) you will see that non-renewable subscriptions are not restored by the system; it is your app's responsibility to track the user's subscription status on your own server.

> - **Non-renewable subscriptions**. Subscriptions that don’t involve delivering episodic content. Examples include access to a database of historic photos or a collection of flight maps. It’s your app’s responsibility to make the subscription available on all of the user’s devices and to let users restore the purchase. This product type is often used when your users already have an account on your server that you can use to identify them when restoring content. Expiration and the duration of the subscription are also left to your app (or your server) to implement and enforce.

Accordingly you will not see a non-renewing subscription in the restored purchases, so what you are seeing is expected both in test and production.

Auto renewing subscriptions are restorable since Apple's server is tracking the active subscription for you.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, thanks for the answer.  However, I have another question then please. Apple says that all purchases need to be available on all devices owned by the user. If thats's the case, then how is it possible to restore purchases on each devise, if you cannot get the historic purchases?  (I am maintaining the subscription expiry date on my server for an account with my app, but what happens if the user signs in with a different app account on another devise they own?)

Comment: In the case of non-renewing subscriptions the subscription is associated with the account on your server, not the iTunes account, so it will/should be "restored" on another device if they log in with the same application account on that device.

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean `restorePurchases` will return a result set if I use a different devise owned by the same user? Do you see my problem? Apple require purchases to be restored to all owned devises, but `restorePurchases` doesn't work for "Non-Renewing Subscription" purchases.

Comment: Only if they have auto renewing subscription or non-consumable purchases. Non-renewing subscription and consumable purchases are never restored by Apple.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify,  "Non-Renewing Subscription" purchases don't need to be maintained  on all the users devises?

Comment: It is up to you. Generally it is "nice" if you make this possible. You also need to consider the case where the user replaces their device and doesn't restore from a backup; logging back into your app with their account from your server should reactivate their subscription but Apple will not expect a "restore" button

Comment: Great, thank you, that makes my life easier. I thought that Apple may enforce this all devise policy. Yes, my apps user account does maintain their subscription, so if they log on any devise, with my apps user account, the subscription is maintained. Appreciate the advise.

Comment: I have read something contrary to this. It says for "Non-Renewing Subscriptions", `You’re also required to make the subscription available to any device owned by the user.`  Please see here https://www.raywenderlich.com/147629/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscriptions-tutorial

Comment: @Richard, yes you should definitely do this. My comment was misleading.