# Read/Write to iCloud

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Due to Apples policy that any purchases have to be available on all the users owned devices, I need to store a value on the users `iCloud` so I can keep track of their purchases.

I am using Ionic, and wondering if there's a useful Cordova plugin that will do this job?

Here is a possible solution? But I cannot seem to get it to work, so was wondering if anyone has done this successfully, and what they used?

[Cordova plugin](https://github.com/alexdrel/cordova-plugin-icloudkv).

Thanks

I have read that `BackupWebStorage` may work, but am struggling to find examples.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to do this through iCloud. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

Comment: I am using `Non-Renewing Subscription` purchases, and the `restore purchases` function for these don't return anything. So I think the only way is to persist the value somewhere, and `iCloud` is the obvious place linked to the users iOS account. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079214/ios-restore-purchases-in-testflight

Answer (score 0):

The [iCloudKV plugin](https://github.com/alexdrel/cordova-plugin-icloudkv) you mentioned should be good enough to read/write in iCloud.

But you may have to wait atleast a minute to read the value from iCloud as this plugin dont guarantees real time data sync and also there seems to be no plugin that does real time syncing as its system controlled.